# How to replace part of text with new string using replaceFirst()?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn from [this toturials](https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0320.html). 
I wish to replace the `carIndex` with `10`.

Here is my code:

```
String price = "//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/main/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[carIndex]/div/a/div[3]/div[1]";

price.replaceFirst("(?:carIndex)", Integer.toString(1));
System.out.println("Price is: "+price);
```

But it always return me

```
Price is: //*[@id="app"]/div/main/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[carIndex]/div/a/div[3]/div[1]
```

So, it does not work for me. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `replaceFirst` returns the new String and does not edit the String in place. Strings in Java are immutable. You can reassign it by doing `price = price.replaceFirst("(?:carIndex)", Integer.toString(10))`. I assume that should be a 10 and not a 1?

Comment: `price = price.replaceFirst(..., ...);`

Answer (score 0):

because `String` is immutable in Java, `replaceFirst` returns the modified string and does not modify the original string 
so, re-assign

```
String price = "//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/main/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[carIndex]/div/a/div[3]/div[1]";

price = price.replaceFirst("(?:carIndex)", Integer.toString(10));
System.out.println("Price is: "+price);
```